# Future minimum pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, minimum

I have a time series in a Pandas DataFrame for which I want to add a new column with the (future) minimum values. Specifically, imagine I have the following values in my time series:

```
 VAL
 1 
 0 
 4 
 3 
 2 
 3 
 4
```

I would like to find the minimum values "looking forward". For example, the minimum for the first 2 values is 0, then for the next three values is 2 (0 is no longer considered because, even if it's the overall minimum, it's already in the past), then 3 and finally 4.

```
 VAL   MIN
 1     0
 0     0
 4     2
 3     2
 2     2
 3     3
 4     4
```

Any ideas how I can do this efficiently with Pandas or Numpy? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flip it, use [`np.minimum.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html), flip it back -

```
In [252]: df['MIN'] = np.minimum.accumulate(df['VAL'][::-1])[::-1]

In [253]: df
Out[253]: 
   VAL  MIN
0    1    0
1    0    0
2    4    2
3    3    2
4    2    2
5    3    3
6    4    4
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [`cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummin.html)

```
df['MIN'] = df.VAL[::-1].cummin()[::-1]
```

---

```
    VAL  MIN
0    1    0
1    0    0
2    4    2
3    3    2
4    2    2
5    3    3
6    4    4
```

Answer (score 3):

We can using `expanding` with `min`

```
df['New']=df.VAL.iloc[::-1].expanding(min_periods=1).min()
```